# Error trying to do logical replication between PostgreSQL and AWS Aurora PostgreSQL could not connect to the publisher: could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to create a subscription.

It works well when I create it on a PostgreSQL instance or cluster (to PostgreSQL).

But when I try to do logical replication from PostgreSQL to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL I see the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not connect to the publisher: could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "my-db.dfsfdsfsdfd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (10.2.5.7) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Some notes:

- I updated the parameter group to enable replication: `rds.logical_replication` (from 0 to 1)
- The RDS policy has enough permissions.
- Both DBs are in the same VPC, same subnets and share the security group
- I can connect to both DBs, and as I said, subscription works if instead of using Aurora I use PostgreSQL

Any idea why this could be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: In logical replication, the connection creation flow and the data flow are in opposite directions.  Can you clarify which side is which, and for the one that is not Aurora, what is it?  RDS?  Your own install of community PostgreSQL running on EC2?

Comment: Thanks for your concern @jjanes
Yes. Both are RDS. One is RDS PostgreSQL the other is RDS Aurora PostgreSQL.
I'm creating the subscription in RDS Aurora using the info of the PostgreSQL DB (my-db.dfsfdsfsdfd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com)